# Any mock tool which will return a preset JSON string?

Tags: json, backbone.js

I would be wanting a tool which can mock a RESTFul server and it should return the preset JSON data which I have mapped for a particular URL.

For ex: If I call   http://ccccc.com/api/users  , the mockup tool should return users ( which I have already preset ) in JSON format.

This might be useful when I create client side code with backbone or jquery to get back the models using an ajax call.

Any suggestions for this kind of mockup tool ?

Note: Creating a servlet which reads the incoming GET url and reads the preset JSON from a file and outputting it as JSON string is possible. But I am looking for a tool which will do this for me.

Comment: Why mockito in the question tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org/) is what you're looking for. In particular the [sinon.fakeServer](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#fakeServer) API.

Comment: Btw here is short slide how to use this in your app, not just in a unit test. http://emdin.info/r/sinon-talk/#1

Comment: its too complicated for a backbone learner like me.,learning the spec and the syntax for jasmine & sinon. What I would want is a simpler tool.

Comment: @TitoCheriachan, you don't need to use Jasmine with sinon. Look at the examples in the slideshow Andreas Köberle linked above. It's only few lines of code to mock a REST endpoint with sinon. I'm afraid it doesn't get much simpler than that.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/homerquan/kakuen

Mock up RESTful webservices simply by editing text files, e.g.,

GET_*#book#123#authors.json ==> GET /book/123/authors
POST*_#book@id=123.json ==> POST /book?id=123

For json, a schema-based mockup is supported, e.g., in sample_server/mocks/GET__#search@q=js.json
e.g.,

```
"@KAKUEN_ITEM(offset)": {
    "@KAKUEN_TYPE": "natural",
    "@KAKUEN_PARAM": {
        "min": 1,
        "max": 20
    }
}
```

will be offset:12